# Function not receiving string from shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

I'm trying to write a function that will use a string (which will be a url once working) sent from a shortcode, but all it's sending back is the default value in the function.

My shortcode is

> [youtube-thumb-url videoUrl="test"]

My function is below:

```
add_shortcode('youtube-thumb-url', 'get_youtube_thumb_url_func');
function get_youtube_thumb_url_func($atts)
{
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'videoUrl' => 'urlhere',
    ), $atts));

return $videoUrl;
}
```

Instead of returning "test", it's returning "urlhere". If 'urlhere' is left empty, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like you can not use upper case like that in a shortcode. Instead of `videoUrl`, use `video-url`:

```
function get_youtube_thumb_url_func( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'video-url' => 'urlHere',
        ), $atts, 'youtube-thumb-url' );

    return $atts['video-url'];
}
add_shortcode( 'youtube-thumb-url', 'get_youtube_thumb_url_func' );
```

And your shortcode:

> [youtube-thumb-url video-url="test"]

This is the final function that I tested before posting.